# Find the common ratio, if the sum of the first $8$ terms in a geometric progression is equal to $17$ times the sum of its first $4$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

> Find the common ratio, if the sum of the first $8$ terms in a geometric progression (GP) is equal to $17$ times the sum of its first $4$ terms.

So far I have got 
$$a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+ar^4+ar^5+ar^6+ar^7=17(a+ar+ar^2+ar^3).$$
How do I proceed without using the sum of GP formula? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can you correct your typos please?

Comment: I think you meant "of the sum.."

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+ar^4+ar^5+ar^6+ar^7=17(a+ar+ar^2+ar^3)$$

$$a(1+r+r^2+r^3)+ar^4(1+r+r^2+r^3)=17a(1+r+r^2+r^3)$$

---

Hint 2:

After the above step, we can gather everything onto the left-hand side and then factor:

$$ar^4(1+r+r^2+r^3)-16a(1+r+r^2+r^3)=0$$
$$a(r^4-16)(1+r+r^2+r^3)=0$$

Can you see what to do from here?

Comment: Thank you very much, it sure helped!

Comment: do you minus a(1+r+r2+r3) from both sides?? wouldnt a(1+r+r2+r3) get cancel out leaving 16a instead?

Comment: @MERcurialKG What I did was to subtract $17a(1+r+r^2+r^3)$ from both sides to make the right-hand side $0$. This doesn't cancel out the $(1+r+r^2+r^3)$, though! If it helps, you could write $x = a(1+r+r^2+r^3)$, so that we have $$x+r^4x=17x.$$ Then subtract $17x$ from both sides to get $r^4x-16x=0$. Now, $x$ is still $a(1+r+r^2+r^3)$, so it's important to see that the $(1+r+r^2+r^3)$ is still there. In fact, it would be better to write it out again: using $x$ is only temporarily helpful to get a better grasp of factoring, but we probably shouldn't use it...

Comment: ... because it unnecessarily introduces a new variable and hides important information about $a$ and $r$. So the moral is, you're allowed to do a trick like this if it helps with factoring, but just remember to change the $x$ back sooner rather than later. For the problem at hand, see if you can factor $1+r+r^2+r^3$ in a similar way to how we did $a+ar+\cdots+ar^7$.

Answer (score -1):

$a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+ar^4+ar^5+ar^6+ar^7=17(a+ar+ar^2+ar^3)$

$a(1+r+r^2+r^3)+a^4(1+r+r^2+r^3)=17a(1+r+r^2+r^3)$

Cancel out $a(1+r+r^2+r^3)$ to get:

$1+a^3=17$

or, $a^3=16$

Thus, $a=2\sqrt[3]2$

Comment: Wow thanks! Cannot believe it was that easy!

Comment: should i round the answer?

Comment: This is incorrect: you can only 'cancel out' a term from each side if it is nonzero. For example, if we had $x^2=x$, then cancelling out an $x$ from each side gives $x=1$, yet we should also have $x=0$. This is why it is safer to factor.

Comment: Thanks, @Théophile, also can you please clear things up for me? In chrys answer, he said a4(1+r+r2+r3) is equal to ar4+ar5+ar6+ar7 so if a4 x r3 is equal to ar7??? Sorry and thanks!!!

Comment: @MERcurialKG Yes, that is another mistake: certainly $a^4$ was intended to be $ar^4$. I'll add some detail to my own answer to show the steps.

Comment: @Théophile Thanks!